# Override Bootstrap's default width for Mobile xs, Tablet sm, Laptop md

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

Bootstrap responsive grid responds to different sizes of the screen. For example, once it reached 768px, it switches to Tablet sm.

I would like to override this to make it slightly smaller, like 480px.

I experimented with some variables in http://getbootstrap.com/customize but unsuccessful in getting the grid to respond correctly.

Comment: Can't you just change the javascript? Like take a look at the file that's making it change the modifications. I'm sure it's like if 786px do that

Comment: the customize url that you supplied is the best option for altering the associated `@media` queries for bootstrap's grid system. Pay particular attention to the "Media queries breakpoints", "Grid system" and "Container sizes" sections of the customize section.